# cordova build -could not remove file (code EACCES)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using cordava the package but using the command :
$ cordova build
I get an error , corrected the PATH but still, some will have a response

thanks

```
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js

mkdir: path already exists: /home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www

cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml

cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/root-master/app-prueba/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:978:15)
    at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:155:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:105:21
    at Array.map (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:70:40
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi looks like there is an error while installing the plugin(s).
try to remove the plugin and add then again.
and also if possible remove the platform and add again.
I have ran into same problem but doing the above things worked for me so many times.